# Why is there no broom-flying license test for wizards?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-transportation, flying-brooms

At Hogwart students learn how to fly, but nobody check their flying abilities. Brooms can be compared to bicycles, and some countries require bicycle licensing. Why are there are no laws governing brooms?

Comment: There's a department of [Broom Regulatory Control](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/ministry-of-magic/department-of-transportation/broom-regulatory-control/). It's not clear what they do

Comment: Note that this book series was written by a British author and that there's no need for a *bike* licence in the UK

Comment: @Valorum Nor is it in the US, two of the largest audiences for _Harry Potter_.

Comment: But riding a broom is more comparable to driving a car or flying a plane than riding a bike and both the UK and the USA require licenses for operating cars and planes.  If wizard kids don't have to be tested and licensed to do so a lot of them should fall off their brooms.

Comment: @M.A.Golding there are implications throughout the series that minor accidents are less dangerous to wizards than to huggles, because they instinctively use magic to protect themselves. Like Neville bouncing after being dropped out of a window. Falling off a broom is almost certainly no big deal.

Comment: What countries require bicycle licensing?

Comment: Why are they compared to bicycles? Bicycles can't fly. Wouldn't they be more analogous to small planes?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I don't think there's one. Switzerland required residents to buy an insurance for their bikes until 2011, which originally came with a small number plate (later a sticker for the bicycle frame).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The in-universe reason that broom transportation remains unregulated is that it is actually easy; and moreover, in spite of appearances, flying around on a broom is not actually that dangerous.  Falls are uncommon and apparently easily treated (even if they might be likely to be fatal for muggles, or in real life).

The out-of-universe reason is that Rowling wanted her hero to become involved in quidditch, the sport she had invented, in the very first book.  This necessitated that he be a skillful broom pilot practically right from the start.  This, in turn, meant that flying a broom had to be both a relatively easy thing to learn (although not necessarily to master) and that it not require licensing.  It is, in fact, treated much like bicycling in the English-speaking world.  In either case, riding is a skill that does have to be taught and practiced, but it can be mastered quickly by children, who are, by the time they are pre-teens, allowed to ride with little or no adult supervision.